# Update the privileges section in the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, privileges, help-center

The [privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) section in the help center should be updated with recent change in the privilege threshold.

There was a change in privilege thresholds on 3 September 2017. The new change implemented was adding a minimum reputation for posting selfanswered question. According to this change, a user needs a minimum reputation of 15 to self answer their question. All the privilege thresholds are given in detail in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared/160292#160292) answer.

[image]

This change is not reflected in the help center.

[image]

So, the privileges section should be updated with this change.

Comment: There are more privileges in that table which aren’t documented in the help center. I believe I’ve seen a post by a Stack Overflow employee stating that’s by design.

Comment: Also, while I made that change a few weeks ago, the rule itself is probably way older but not widely known.

Comment: Btw, it is clarified in [relevant page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) of help centre.